# Select query for the percentage of rows that have a given value?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, percentage

If I have the table below, how do I write a `SELECT` query to return any TYPE where the percentage of rows that have a value of 1 is greater than 50%?
So in this case, it would only return B, as 66% of rows with TYPE B have a value of 1.

```
TYPE  VALUE
-------------
A     0
A     0
A     1
A     0
B     0
B     1
B     1
C     0
C     0
C     0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select type
from t
group by t
having avg(case when value = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5;
```

You can include the `avg()` expression on the `select` to get the proportion.